# What's the etymology of "limerence"?

Tags: etymology, psychology

[Limerence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerence) is basically a word coined in 1979 by American psychologist Dorothy Tennov. It's a very obscure term, even among psychologists. In fact Tennov's followers in 2010 remarked how few professional clinical psychologists even were [aware of the concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerence#Continuing_research). Nevertheless the Wikipedia article on it is about 3300 words long. The word basically means a crush/infatuation with someone that is often unrequited and obsessive.

Whenever I look up the word, its etymology is usually given as:

> coined by Dorothy Tennov (1928–2007), American psychologist

This doesn't help that much.

Wiktionary gives the etymology of:

> From arbitrary first element +‎ -ence.

This makes no sense to me. The website Wordnik gives an etymology, which purportedly is sourced from Wiktionary, and says:

> The coinages are arbitrary; there is no specific etymology.

This has me confused, as I don't understand what these mean.

Comment: The etymology of the work *grok* is that it comes from Robert A. Heinlein's book *A Stranger In a Strange Land*. He made it up. There is no reason to suppose that every word has more of a reason behind it than "I threw some letters together that looked good."

Comment: This is tricky. >2m Google hits, but no dictionary definition that I can find other than in UD. Quasi off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

I found a blog with the following quote:

> But here’s the thing. This beautiful word has no etymology. None at
>   all. In the words of its creator:  “I first used the term ‘amorance’
>   then changed it back to ‘limerence’… It has no roots whatsoever. It
>   looks nice. It works well in French. Take it from me it has no
>   etymology whatsoever.” (Tennov in the Observer 11 Sept. 1977)
>
> Its official etymology is therefore “limer” (arbitrary syllable) +
>   “ence”.
>   [Link to blog](https://awesomefact.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/limerence/)

Well this was rather anticlimactic, but this account squares with the etymology given in Wiktionary or Wordnik, that is, it's based on a made-up word part with the -ence morpheme attached to it. It was completely made-up by the originator back in the late 70s.

Comment: "It works well in French. " See the etym. of the Fr. root *limer* here: (**2.**) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/limer#Etymology Huh?

Comment: @Kris Haha, but she said it had no root https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=root Great, just when I was happy that I found out she made up the entire word, now I want to know if she was aware of the French slang, or if it even existed in 1978. Oh well, I ain't going to research that.